# My app not working on Android 7.0 and older versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version

I'm creating a tourist application with google map in app. My app works perfectly on Android 7.1 and higher versions, but when i install on Android 7.0 and older versions i have problem "[App Name] Unfortunately has stopped working".

I'm using `compileSdkVersion=25 , minSDK=14 and targetSDK=28` (I tried changing them to SDK 21 , 22, 23, but noting works).

This is my build gradle file,

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28

    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [googleMapsKey: 'AIzaSyDCwHrHPFZmIMfqKlmmYIstb4exYAhYMgU']

    }
}
android {
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Actual result is working everything fine ona Android 7.1 and higher versions bit not working on lower android versions.

**EDIT:**

This is logcat from connected device where my app crash

```
> 08-28 13:28:09.703 22375-22375/? E/Zygote: v2 08-28 13:28:09.703
> 22375-22375/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10226 08-28
> 13:28:09.703 22375-22375/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
> 08-28 13:28:09.707 22375-22375/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0 08-28
> 13:28:09.712 22375-22375/? W/SELinux: SELinux
> selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],
> Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0010, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1] 08-28
> 13:28:09.715 22375-22375/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup:
> seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768,
> pkgname=com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide 08-28 13:28:09.722
> 22375-22375/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 08-28 13:28:09.762
> 22375-22375/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled:
> cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service 08-28
> 13:28:09.878 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide W/System:
> ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
> /data/app/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide-1/lib/arm64 08-28
> 13:28:09.968 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide W/art:
> Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
> android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
> would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 08-28 13:28:10.603
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: ThreadedRenderer.create()
> translucent=false 08-28 13:28:10.617
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/InputTransport: Input
> channel constructed: fd=57 08-28 13:28:10.618
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: setView =
> DecorView@46a4596[SplashScreen] touchMode=true 08-28 13:28:10.625
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: dispatchAttachedToWindow 08-28
> 13:28:10.672 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: Relayout returned:
> oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x27
> surface={isValid=true 490731848192} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
> 08-28 13:28:10.673 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize()
> mSurface={isValid=true 490731848192} hwInitialized=true 08-28
> 13:28:10.697 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0,
> 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1 08-28 13:28:10.697
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 08-28
> 13:28:10.697 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide
> D/ViewRootImpl@5abccb1[SplashScreen]:
> mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true
> 490731848192} 08-28 13:28:10.699
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide V/InputMethodManager:
> Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@a778517 nm :
> com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide ic=null 08-28 13:28:10.699
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide I/InputMethodManager:
> [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus 08-28
> 13:28:10.713 22375-22403/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/libEGL:
> loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so 08-28 13:28:10.714
> 22375-22388/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/InputTransport: Input
> channel constructed: fd=58 08-28 13:28:10.748
> 22375-22403/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide I/OpenGLRenderer:
> Initialized EGL, version 1.4 08-28 13:28:10.748
> 22375-22403/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap
> behavior 1 08-28 13:28:10.755
> 22375-22403/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/mali_winsys: EGLint
> new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig,
> egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns
> 0x3000, [1440x2560]-format:1 08-28 13:28:10.761
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM 08-28 13:28:10.769
> 22375-22375/com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main Process: com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide, PID: 22375
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too
> large(132710400bytes) bitmap. at
> android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
> at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420) at
> android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
> at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:18585) at
> android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:18521) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18309) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966) at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752) at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:18321) at
> com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:919) at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296) at
> android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
> at
> android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
> at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:806) at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3128) at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2924) at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2516) at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515) at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702) at
> android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638) at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: don't think you should be posting your api key here, also, check the logs for why it's crashing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: it must be showing some error ..please share the log also

Comment: Can you please share stacktrace?

Comment: It's working fine on emulator. What can I do?

Comment: connect the crashing device to your computer and run the app, then check the logs

Comment: Okay i check but i dont know whats the problem so i posted as answer you can see it

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.stefanovski.bojan.bitolaguide, PID: 2375 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap`

Comment: Better add the stacktrace by editing your question...that is not an answer...

Comment: @MartinMarconcini What should I do now ?

Comment: Edit your original post to contain this log information, don't add it as an answer

Comment: I have edited, but whtas the error can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubt about `cruncherEnabled = false` usage.

You have `RuntimeException` that says:

> Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.

With option `cruncherEnabled = false` you prevent image optimization during the build process that may affect on some devices. If you want to prevent optimization on some specific images please put them in the raw resource directory but don't disable cruncher when you are building.